# Laravel application: Do I need a new application for new subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel, web-services

In my server, I had a `shop.mycompany.com` folder and I built a Laravel application inside it for handling the shopping related process. So, ppl can access `shop.mycompany.com/item?name=asdf` to shop. I think `shop.mycompany.com` is a subdomain of `mycompany.com`, please correct me if I am wrong.

I would like to have another subdomain, `comment.mycompany.com`, to handle customers' comments. Maybe I will send a mail to customer with the link `comment.mycompany.com/customer?id=1`, so they can leave there comment.

My question is can I use the Laravel application in `shop.mycompany.com` folder to build the `comment.mycompany.com` route. I took a look in Laravel, it has a domain function, is it suitable to use in my case? I think I can build route for `comment.shop.mycompany.com`, not sure about building `shop.mycompany.com` route.

Thank you for your time, please let me know if I miss any information to make the decision.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don‘t need an entirely new Laravel application. Laravel can route on whatever routes you give it:

```
Route::domain('comment.example.com')->group(function () {
    // Comment routes here
});

Route::domain('{shop}.example.com')->group(function () {
    // Shop routes here
});
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation how it actually works ?

Comment: @AqibJaved What do you mean? There are some routes. Laravel’s router matches the request against them. Read Laravel’s docs (and publicly-available source code) if you want to know how Laravel works.

Comment: in my case, my current 'APP_URL' = 'shop.example.com' and my application is located in 'shop.example.com' folder. In order to use domain, do I have to change them into 'example.com'
thanksssss!!!!

Comment: Change your virtual host and DNS record to accept any subdomains. ````*.example.com````

Answer (score 0):

I all depends how your hosting is set up.

if you do not have a subdomain pointed to a different folder you can basically use *.yourdomain.com

This article will may help you further.
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/laravel-subdomians/

Comment: thank you so much~ I will take a look!!!!!!

Comment: if it works, please upvote my anwser...

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::domain('shop.' . env('DOMAIN_NAME'))->group(function () {
    // Shop related api goes here
});

Route::domain('comment.' . env('DOMAIN_NAME'))->group(function () {
    // Comment related api goes here
});
```

Subject to your main Domain URL is defined as in `.env` file

```
APP_URL="https://${DOMAIN_NAME}" // This one is neccessary for your app to work for static assets and non domain URLs
DOMAIN_NAME=mycompany.com
```

Comment: can you please add some explanation how it actually works ?

Comment: in my case, my current 'APP_URL' = 'shop.example.com' and my application is located in 'shop.example.com' folder. can I use you method?
How APP_URL is interacted with the static assets and non domain URLs, I am not understand this part. sorry